# Does Roslyn conflict with ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, roslyn

This may be to ambiguous a question but I'm still going to ask.  I have had Roslyn Preview turned on in VS2013 for awhile now but recently I purchased ReSharper 9.  While they were both "active" VS did not seem to work very well and I wasn't able to access certain ReSharper features even though I had set the keyboard settings correctly.

So, I know that ReSharper doesn't and won't use Roslyn but is it compatible running together?

Comment: I'm not running VS2013 any more, but VS2015 Preview + R# works okay. (Although R# doesn't know about some C# 6 features.)

Comment: Thanks, I wonder if it's a VS2013 thing.  Maybe I should just switch to 2015 :)

Comment: http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/04/10/resharper-and-roslyn-qa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, R# is meant to be compatible with Roslyn. Since Roslyn isn't out yet and still changing, there could be some bugs but that's understandable and would be fixed with a future update for R# 9.

In any case, I have been working with both (on VS2015) without any issues.

Comment: But in the website it says, it wont use Rosyln, @i3arnon

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, ReSharper 9 provides *initial* support for Roslyn, since neither Roslyn nor Visual Studio, which uses it, have been released. Rest assured that when VS2015 *does* release, ReSharper will support it in its entirety. But since the final feature set has not yet been determined, it is unreasonable to expect the current version of ReSharper to support every C# feature that Roslyn has. Give it time :)

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but for future readers, I'd like to clarify that Roslyn is an API that _could_ provide the backbone for Resharper, but [JetBrains is adamently refusing to use that API](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/04/10/resharper-and-roslyn-qa/).  Whereas, I think you're referring to the language features that Roslyn was implementing and that Resharper could have also implemented (which they have).